# ROW_NUMBER and PARTITION BY in Tableau

Tags: sql, data-visualization, tableau-api, window-functions

Can I do the following in Tableau -

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY A,B ORDER BY C) AS X
```

Based on the syntax in the Tableau official document I am doing the below but getting an error

> {PARTITION [A],[B]: {ORDERBY [C]:ROW_NUMBER() }}
>
> Error - Expected '}' following the expression

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you can do these calculations in Tableau Prep only.  Tableau desktop, tableau public, tableau Server edition do not support these calculations as of now.

Answer (score 0):

In Tableau desktop you can use a table calculation to do this.

1. Create a new calculated field, called index with the formula: index()
2. Right click on the index calculation field (step 1) and convert to discrete
3. Place the index calculated field into rows along with the columns you want including the one you want to partition by. This shows that index is a table calculation
4. Right click on the index in rows and edit table calculation. Compute using: select 'Specific Dimensions'; and for 'Restart every' select the column you want to partition by
5. Use the sort functionality to sort the view by your chosen field

For this to work you need to have the data you want to partition by in the view. This is purely a workaround.

Comment: Apart from this being workaround, the major drawback of this method is that the values like row_number aren't hard-coded.  These keep on changing as per view/context generated.  Whereas in Tableau prep these can be hard coded and be thereafter used in any context.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a way at this moment. I did it in SQL before bringing the data into Tableau.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Row_numbers() can use only in the Tableau Prep Biulder

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32890204)